# .net: How to get data from array index?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, .net-4.0

**Code :**

```
  byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
   var read =  (fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)));
   long flength = fs.Length;
   int fSize = int.Parse(flength.ToString());
   MWArray[] in_Arrw = new MWArray[((int)read)];

   MWNumericArray arr = new MWNumericArray(fSize, 1, bytes);

   ChordRecognizer hj = new ChordRecognizer();

   MWArray in_Arr = hj.estimateCost(arr);
   fs.Close();
```

I am unable to get what it returns in `in_Arr = hj.estimateCost(arr)`, throws exception if I try to access `in_Arr[0]`, can see in images

Please help.

**Quick watch:**

[image]

.
[image]

**Stack Trace :**

> at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray.ArrayIndexer(MWArray srcArray,
>   Int32[] indices)   at
>   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray.get_Item(Int32[] indices)
>   at 
>   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray.get_Item(Int32[] indices)

Comment: And the exception is? Type and message please.

Comment: hj.estimateCost(arr);  Please provide code for estimateCost method also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pictures you posted I see that your array has more than one dimension.

Since this is not a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) you cannot acces an item of the array if you don't supply an index for each dimension (so to speak). In other words, your array is something like `YourType[m,n,p]` and not `YourType[m][n,p]`, so to acces an item of `YourType[m,n,p]` you need to supply 3 indices (e.g. `var item = in_arr[0,0,0];`) not only one.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting a "Invalid Index exception". I think [0] is not the right way to access the object